# How to compute Topk IoU in semantic segmentation using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

Given outputs of a neural network `outputs` and a ground-truth `label`. `outputs.shape = (N, C, H, W)` and `label.shape = (N, H ,W)`, where `N` is the batch size, `C` is the number of classes, `H` and `W` are crop sizes. Each element of `label` is in the range of `[0, ..., C-1]`. That is, `0 <= label[i,j,k] <= C-1` for all `i,j,k`. I want to compute top3 IoU of `outputs` with respect to `label`, so I need a one-hot version of its top3 output. For example

```
N, C, H, W = 1, 4, 2, 2
outputs = torch.rand((N, C, H, W))
label = torch.arange(C).reshape(N, H, W)
_, index = torch.topk(outputs, k=3, dim=1)
top3 = torch.zeros((N, C, H, W))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(H):
        for k in range(W):
            c = label[i, j, k]
            if c in index[i, :, j, k]:
                top3[i, c, j, k] = 1

outputs

tensor([[[[0.8002, 0.6733],
          [0.7034, 0.5039]],

         [[0.8401, 0.9226],
          [0.7963, 0.6157]],

         [[0.1063, 0.0310],
          [0.2489, 0.9920]],

         [[0.8279, 0.9109],
          [0.4737, 0.2299]]]])

label

tensor([[[0, 1],
         [2, 3]]])

index

tensor([[[[1, 1],
          [1, 2]],

         [[3, 3],
          [0, 1]],

         [[0, 0],
          [3, 0]]]])

top3

tensor([[[[1., 0.],
          [0., 0.]],

         [[0., 1.],
          [0., 0.]],

         [[0., 0.],
          [0., 0.]],

         [[0., 0.],
          [0., 0.]]]])
```

Then I can use `top3` to compute top3 IoU. There is a [version](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-topk-results-from-segmentation-one-hot-masks-but-keep-dims/119352) to compute top3 pixel-wise accuracy, but it creates a lot of false 1s and so cannot be used to compute IoU.

```
expand = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(index)
top3 = expand.transpose(1, 4).sum(dim=4) 

top3

tensor([[[[0, 1],
          [0, 0]],

         [[1, 0],
          [1, 1]],

         [[1, 1],
          [1, 1]],

         [[1, 1],
          [1, 1]]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an efficient (vectorized) solution would look something like this:

1. Compute top k index maps `[N,k,H,W]`
2. Check each of the k index maps against the ground truth labels `[N,k,H,W]`
3. Sum across the k maps

followed by some arithmetic to get the specific value you care about.

```
#1. Compute top k index maps
k = 3 # but works for arbitrary k <= C
topk = torch.topk(outputs,k = k, dim = 1)  # [N,C,H,W] in, [N,k,H,W] out

#2. Check for label equality against each index map
labels_expanded = labels.unsqueeze(1).expand(N,k,H,W] # tensor view of size [N,k,H,W]
tp = torch.where(labels_expanded == topk,1,0) 
# result is # [N,k,H,W] where a 1 at position [i,j,m,n] means that label[i,m,n] = topk[i,j,m,n] (a true positive) and a 0 indicates otherwise 

#3. sum across all k maps
tp_sum = tp.sum(dim = 1) # now of shape [N,H,W]
```

All that remains is a bit of elementary IOU math (as IOU is TP/ (FP + FN + TP) for pixelwise tasks), but I'll leave the specifics of that up to you as you may want to exclude any background class (otherwise IOU reduces simply to accuracy (TP / total, or accuracy). Personally I find the notion of IOU for dense semantic segmentation tasks where every pixel has a label to be semantically misleading but that's outside of the scope of this question.